# Why, while loop is running infinitely?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, prime-factoring

I want to find the prime factors of the number 600851475143.

I have used range() method in for loop but no result, they both(for and while) are running for infinitely.

```
l=[]
nn=600851475143
n=nn-1
while n>1:
    if nn%n==0:
        j=n-1
        while j>1:
            if n%j==0:
                break
            j-=1
        else:
            l.append(n)
    n-=1         
print(l)
```

please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Project euler is great. I really suggest you do a little bit of research (even wikipedia can help) You will learn a lot more once you do the reading. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not.
It's just hella long and you are decrementing by 1

here's the output:

```
(...)
 12     print(n)
 13     n-=1
(...)


600850312864
600850312863
600850312862
600850312861
600850312860
600850312859
600850312858
600850312857
600850312856
600850312855
600850312854
```

[Here's a solution](https://github.com/unamatasanatarai/projecteuler/blob/master/lib.py#L131) that will give you the desired result `[71, 839, 1471, 6857]`

```
nn=600851475143
def prime_factors(number):
    factors = []
    divisor = 2

    while(number > 2):
        if (number % divisor == 0):
            factors.append(divisor)
            number = number / divisor
        else:
            divisor += 1

    return factors

print(prime_factors(nn))
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the point of (number > 2) condition in while loop, the result can also be produced by (number > 1) and which I think should be considered since theoretically we stop factorization when the number becomes 1 right?